# HighCharts : Note/Detail on a point

Tags: highcharts

I need to know if it's possible to add some text (note/detail) on a specific point, in addition to the tooltip.

I use HighCharts Version 3.0.9.

Actually I use a *click* event on a points to show a popup detail in html . But i want to know if there is a native solution with HighCharts.

Like :

```
[
 { 
   x: 11,
   y: 11,
   note: {
      text: "Some text",
   }
 },
 { 
   x: 16,
   y: 17
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. You have two options:

- write your own `tooltip.formatter`, to get that value
- use `tooltip.pointFormat` to create pattern for points

Second example (easier): http://jsfiddle.net/mPb4A/

```
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}: {point.options.note.text}</b><br/>'
    },
```

Only limitation of second solution is that each point requires `note` property, otherwise you will get error in JS saying that `Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`.